# HighCharts: Positioning label on chart agnostic of legend size

Tags: highcharts

I am building a pie chart where the labels for the data points can very greatly in length, the legend is configured to be vertical and positioned on the left side.
I have added a label element to the bottom of the chart that shows the total of all data points.

The problem I am facing is that the positioning of this label (via the style element) is based on how wide the legend is, which occasionally if the legend is wide enough will be pushed off the right side of the chart.

Does anyone know of a way that I can style this label so that is positioned based solely on the width of the entire chart.

Here is the styling applied to the label (I tried adding the position value but this didn't appear to do anything):

```
style: {
                    top: '325px',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: '-160px',
                    'font-size': '175%'
                }
```

Here is an example of the chart that I'm working with, you can see that the value for the total has bee cut off.

[image: Example chart]

EDIT:
As per Sebastian's comment I was able to effectively solve the issue by using the legend label formatter to limit the length of the series names. Here is the code:

```
labelFormatter: function () {
    var formattedName = this.name;
    if (formattedName.length > 17) {
        formattedName = formattedName.substr(0, 14) + '...';
    }
    return formattedName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use labelFormatter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter ?

Comment: Actually just today I used the formatter to truncate the legend names so that the legend width wouldn't change, it does solve the issue albeit in an indirect way.

Comment: You can take look at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend parametres like width, or try to set useHTML as true.